# Best way to set Wordpress plugin max version for update?

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

Is there a way to set a max update-able version of Wordpress plugins, until they are fully tested in our environment? For example, this
could make sure no users update to NextGen 2.x which is broken in various
ways, until it is verified to not cause conflicts.

I tried the `plugins_api` filter, which works for searching plugins, but it
only changes the displayed version in "add new" plugins page.

Do you have to mirror the WP repository with older versions with some complicated hacks, or is there a simple switch/hook to set the preferred version?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable the plugins from updating you can simply use this plugin :

http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/

Regards

Comment: That just hides all updates from everyone. I found a better way, hooking where it gets transient for plugin_updates.